# Simplest Solution for a Round Table Q

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Company of 3 Turks, 3 British and 3 French sit at a round table.
What is the probability that no two countrymans sitting next to each other?
All the people are different, but sitting orders different by rotations are equal

It seems like that problem
[A round table probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508127/a-round-table-probability-question)

But this is much harder because there are 3 groups, and every group of 3 people.

I counted total choices as 9! / 9 = 8!, but having no ideas how easily count good choices without big "brute force"

Answer (score 2):

Number the people from $1$ to $9,$ with $1,2,3$ Turks, $4,5,6$ Brits, and $7,8,9$ French.  Let $T_{ij}$ be the event that $j$ sits immediately to the right of $i.$ We need to exclude $18$ events:
$$
T_{12},\ T_{21},\ T_{13},\ T_{31},\ T_{23},\ T_{32},\\
T_{45},\ T_{54},\ T_{46},\ T_{64},\ T_{56},\ T_{65},\\
T_{78},\ T_{87},\ T_{79},\ T_{97},\ T_{89},\ T_{98}.
$$
Since we will need to use the principle of inclusion-exclusion, we also need to know about intersections.  Certain intersections are empty: $T_{12}\cap T_{13},$ for example.  Others are not: $T_{12}\cap T_{23}$ and $T_{12}\cap T_{45},$ for example.

Since $T_{12}$ is the set of arrangements in which $2$ always sits immediately to the right of $1,$ we enumerate the event by regarding $12$ as a single "person".  Instead of $8!$ circular permutations, $T_{12}$ has only $7!.$  Similarly,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lvert T_{12}\cap T_{23}\rvert=\lvert T_{12}\cap T_{45}\rvert&=6!\\
\lvert T_{12}\cap T_{23}\cap T_{45}\rvert=\lvert T_{12}\cap T_{45}\cap T_{78}\rvert&=5!
\end{aligned}
$$
and so on.

We also need to count how many non-empty intersections there are of each intersection degree.  First consider degree-$2$ intersections involving only members of a single country, such as $T_{13}\cap T_{32}.$  Such an intersection consists of arrangements in which $1,$ $3,$ and $2$ are seated adjacent to each other in that order.  There are $3\cdot3!$ such intersections, corresponding the three ways to choose the country and the $3!$ ways of ordering the representatives of that country.

Next consider degree-2 intersections involving members of two different countries such as $T_{12}\cap T_{64}.$  There are $\binom{3}{2}\cdot(3\cdot2)^2$ such intersections, corresponding to the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose the two countries and the $(3\cdot2)^2$ ways of selecting, in order, the two representatives from each of those two countries.  Recall that both types of degree-$2$ intersections contain $6!$ elements.

We continue in the same way with degree-$3,$ degree-$4,$ degree-$5,$ and degree-$6$ intersections.  Putting everything together, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
8!&-3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot7!+(3\cdot3!+3\cdot(3\cdot2)^2)\cdot6!-(3\cdot2\cdot3!\cdot(3\cdot2)+(3\cdot2)^3)\cdot5!\\
&+(3\cdot(3!)^2+3\cdot3!\cdot(3\cdot2)^2)\cdot4!-3\cdot(3!)^2\cdot(3\cdot2)\cdot3!+(3!)^3\cdot2!
\end{aligned}
$$
ways of seating the people.  Finally, we divide by $8!$ to obtain the probability.

For an additional illustration of the method by which the coefficients were obtained, consider quadruple intersections.  There are two types: those similar to $T_{12}\cap T_{23}\cap T_{45}\cap T_{56},$ of which there are $3\cdot(3!)^2,$ and those similar to $T_{12}\cap T_{23}\cap T_{45}\cap T_{78},$ of which there are $3\cdot3!\cdot(3\cdot2)^2.$

**Added:** A slight generalization might make the structure clearer.  Let there be $k$ countries with three representatives each.  Then the number of seatings in which no two citizens of a country sit adjacent is, for $k\ge2,$
$$
\sum_{d=0}^{2k}(-1)^d\sum_{p=0}^{\lfloor d/2\rfloor}\frac{k!}{p!\,(d-2p)!\,(k+p-d)!}(3!)^p(3\cdot2)^{d-2p}(3k-1-d)!.
$$
The index $d$ in the outer summation is the degree of intersection.  The index $p$ in the inner summation is the number of countries that are identified with two sets in the intersection, which implies that $d-2p$ countries are identified with one set in the intersection, and $k+p-2$ countries are identified with no sets in the intersection.  The factor $\frac{k!}{p!\,(d-2p)!\,(k+p-d)!}=\binom{k}{p,\,d-2p,\,k+p-d}$ counts the number of ways of identifying the countries in this way, while the factor $(3!)^p(3\cdot2)^{d-2p}$ counts the number of ways of forming the intersection using the identified countries.  Specifically, if a country is identified with two sets in the intersection, that is, with $F_{ab}\cap F_{bc},$ where $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ are the representatives of that country, then there are $3!$ ways of deciding which representative is $a,$ which is $b,$ and which is $c.$  If a country is identified with just one set in the intersection, that is, with $F_{ab},$ then there are $3\cdot2$ ways of deciding which representative of that country is $a$ and which is $b.$

For $k=1,$ the number of seatings is obviously $0.$  The formula above gives the incorrect answer $2$ in this case because the two triple intersections $T_{12}\cap T_{23}\cap T_{31}$ and $T_{13}\cap T_{32}\cap T_{21}$ haven't been excluded.  Such intersections are empty in the case $k>1,$ analyzed above, but non-empty in the case $k=1,$ making the two cases fundamentally different.

Comment: Will, thank you very much for your solution.
It's totally correct and mostly clear for me in understanding.

Comment: I'm not totally happy with the exposition, and have tried to tweak it a bit.  If anything is still unclear, let me know.